# Echo text as suggested prompt in bash

Tags: bash, line-editor

Is it possible to change text that appears after `$PS1`. It is what user inputs. I want to suggest some command hereafter `my_function` is run. Of Course I should be able to modify/delete it using backspace key

```
root@linux: 
root@linux: ls
aplha beta gamma
root@linux: my_function
root@linux: echo_something_here (It should be deletable by me)
```

Comment: About the only way I can think of to do this would be to have a wrapper program controlling the terminal and "typing" the suggested text at an appropriate time. That seems a bit suboptimal though, so I'll see what others come up with.

Comment: The ZSH solution is `print -z`, e.g. `my_function { print "hello world"; print -z echo_something_here }`

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/5378/425040) you can use [`expect`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/expect.1.html) (you might have to install it first):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Get a Bash shell
spawn -noecho bash

# Wait for a prompt (in my case was '$', but your example only put ':')
expect ": "

# store the first argument in a variable
set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]

# Type something
send $arg1

# Hand over control to the user
interact

exit
```

Now you can call it (assuming you saved it as `my_function`):

```
root@linux: ./my_function "some text here"
root@linux: some text here
```

The only undesirable effect might be that it starts a new bash.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then having a support script

```
 #!/bin/bash
 read -ei "$*"
 printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"
```

called for example ~/bin/iedit, then you can say

> eval $( ~/bin/iedit "some text here" )

this will output "some text here", which you can edit. Once you have finished editing it then the resulting command will be executed.

This is not a good example of code. Almost always you want to use "$@" rather than "$*", and one should usually try and avoid using eval. You might want to add a history -s $REPLY as well. Putting these together, the support script could be

```
 #!/bin/bash
 read -ei "$*"
 history -s "$REPLY"
 fc -s
```

and you would invoke it as 'source ~/bin/iedit "some text here"'.